# Game development with Qt: where to look first?

Tags: c++, qt

So, I'm going to develop a Pac-Man clone with Qt. The problem is that I do not really know where to start.

I quickly take a look at the documentation and some demo. I also downloaded some game sources on qt-apps.org. And it seems that there is a lot of ways to develop a game with Qt!

In your experience, which part of Qt should I consider to develop a Pac-Mac clone ?

- The Animation Framework
- The Graphics View Framework
- The Paint System
- Qt Declarative

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think that [QGraphicsView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) framework is the best way. Create a [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html), some QGraphicsItems for the elements of the game. You have collision detection for free.

Most of [KDE games](http://games.kde.org/) are based on the QGraphicsView framework. It is a good fit for simple game development.

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently working on a project providing gaming-specific Qt Quick Components for cross-platform game development, might be of interest: http://v-play.net :)

Answer (score 2):

At the very minimum you will want to look at [QGLWidget](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qglwidget.html).  You can get an OpenGL program up in a few minutes by deriving from QGLWidget, it will create the window, context, handle mouse and keyboard input, etc.  Create a [QTimer](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qtimer.html) to trigger updateGL() every 10-15 ms or so and your good to go.  I think there is a demo somewhere for setting this up, but it has been awhile since I saw it.

If you want to embed widgets into the window, I would look at [QGraphicsView](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qgraphicsview.html).  There is a demo of this called [boxes](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/demos-boxes.html).  Just beware the demo is a tad hard to learn from as several classes are thrown into the same file and it might take a few moments of tracing to figure out where the flow is.

Since you are doing a 2d game, you might want to look at using [QPainter](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qpainter.html) on [top of OpenGL](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/opengl-overpainting.html).  This allows you to draw primitives easily instead of doing them with OpenGL calls.  I never could get this to stop flickering in fullscreen though.

Comment: *"to embed widows"* sounds a bit harsh ;)

Comment: Meh, QPainter is so nineties. One should definitely use QGraphicsView. I am working on a big set of Qt-based games, and porting to QGraphicsView makes the code considerably easier (and even faster, because it schedules the re-rendering automatically). - If you still need OpenGL to make it run fast, you just do view->setViewport(new QGLWidget); and be done.

Answer (score 1):

There's a book about game development in Qt [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584504064), it's a bit old, but it might give you some ideas. But IMHO, Qt is widget based and is a bit slow for a game, you might consider using SDL or OpenGL.

Comment: I think I would not have time to order the book nor read it, I have to return the complete project this Friday ;)

Comment: It seems to me that you have an assignment like this https://engineering.purdue.edu/OOSD/F2008/assignment/assignment4.html. In that case, check out http://kpacman.sourceforge.net for hints.

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing a simulation of rigid bodies with Qt and OpenGL using the PhysX API from Nvidia. If you want to see this approach, look at my project at github: http://github.com/lucassimao/Simulacao-Estereologica

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be:

[Qt Examples And Tutorials](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html)

Perhaps if you need to cheat you may want to look here
[xpacman.tar.gz](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/X11/contrib/games/)

Comment: I love to do things by myself, but I had a quick look at it. And I believe that I'm on the right track! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one place to look could be the Gluon game development framework, which is currently under development. It depends on what you're really aiming for with your PacMan clone, but Gluon may well be what you're after: https://github.com/KDE/gluon

Comment: This answer is of course less relevant to you, since you've got a very short time to do your work in, but it may well be relevant to others with a similar, less time restricted question ;)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is interested in learning how to make GAMES using C++ and Qt, have a look at my YouTube tutorial series. It explains the graphics view framework through a series of videos which build upon a single game that we start in tutorial 1.

[C++ Qt Game Tutorial 8 - Adding Graphics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPs40BrYHkg)

If you are not comfortable with Qt yet, then I REALLY loved VoidRealm's Qt tutorial series, also on youtube ([C++ Qt 1 - Introduction to QT programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KtOzh0StTc&list=PL2D1942A4688E9D63)).