# qt: how to implement canvas rendering

Tags: qt, canvas, graphics

I want to use Qt to write a simple c++ 2d game (kinda-pacman). I've got a model of the app already (pure C++), now I need to implement the rendering part and I'm trying to find the best Qt classes to paint 2D graphics on a canvas. I'm trying to find "Qt canvas" or similar stuff on google but I get stuck with things around QML. I want just a simple canvas (bitmap or whatever) and pure C++. Can someone point me on what to use?

Comment: you may use QWidget and use QPainer, or you can also try Graphics View framework (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html) from Qt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the days of Qt 3, there used to be a QCanvas, but Qt 4 replaced that with the QGraphics Framework, as described [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq19-graphicsview.html)

For games I'd suggest creating a QGraphicsView with a QGraphicsScene and then adding QGraphicsItems or QGraphicsObjects if you want signals and slots.

There's also more info on creating a Pacman-like game [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224155/game-development-with-qt-where-to-look-first)